# Accessing background worker from another form's button click event

Tags: c#

I'm getting my way around c# slowly but surely lol in this code:

```
    // create an instance of the main form
    public formMain _formMain;
    public void btnDynaDotCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_formMain.bgWorker.IsBusy != true)
        {
            this.btnDynaDotCheck.Enabled = false;
            _formMain.bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync("dr_begin_dd_check");
        }
        else
        {
            _formMain.returnMessage("Please wait untill the current task is finished...");
            return;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to access the background worker in formMain.cs from anotherForm.cs there is no errors in VS, but when run i get

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in " and "Additional information: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object."

On this line:

```
if (_formMain.bgWorker.IsBusy != true)
```

So i'm not really getting access in this case eh?

Comment: i guess `_formMain == null` since you did not instantiate it.

Comment: I concur with stefankmitph, your code has declared _forMain, but has not instantiated an instance of that object that your code attempts to manipulate.

Comment: mainform is instantiated, but _formMain is not referring to that instance. There is not need to instantiate a new instance of mainform you already have one. Pass that instance to the constructor of anotherForm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dependency injection to inject a reference to your mainform into the otherone : somewhere in your mainform code do the following :

```
anotherForm _anotherForm = new anotherForm(this);
_anotherForm.Show();
```

assuming you are creating anotherform from code within the mainform, `this` is actually referring to the mainform.
In the constructor of anotherFrom do this :

```
public anotherForm(MainForm formMain){
    _formMain = formMain;
}
```

This is by far the most elegant way to solve this issue. Because it makes clear that there is a dependency from one form to the other and makes the design intention clear.

Using a parent is also fine, but only if the mainform is really a parent of the other form.

Going via Application object will work, but the application object is a global and you hide your dependency that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
_formMain = Application.OpenForms["formMain"];
```

Add this code in button click and try it.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing `_formMain` from `anotherForm`:

I assume `anotherForm` is instantiated and called from `_formMain` like this:

```
anotherForm _anotherForm = new anotherForm();
_anotherForm.Show();
```

there's now several ways to access `_formMain` from `_anotherForm` but the easiest I think is to set `_formMain` as the parent of `_anotherForm`:

```
_anotherForm.Parent = this; // insert before _anotherForm.Show()
```

this way you can get hold of it in `_anotherForm` like this

```
public void btnDynaDotCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    formMain _formMain = this.Parent as formMain;
    if(_formMain != null)
    { 
       ... // do whatever ever you have to do
    }
}
```

but be careful... getting your `BackgroundWorker` in `_formMain` requires public methods you can call and return your `BackgroundWorker`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys :)

I now have:

```
    // create an instance of the formMain
    formMain _formMain = new formMain();
    public void btnDynaDotCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_formMain.bgWorker.IsBusy != true)
        {
            this.btnDynaDotCheck.Enabled = false;
            _formMain.bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync("dr_begin_dd_check");
        }
        else
        {
            _formMain.returnMessage("Please wait untill the current task is finished...");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Which works :) it gets through to the main form:

```
   public void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
        // action to string format
        string action = e.Argument as string;
        if (action == "dr_begin_dd_check")
        {
                    BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        statusLabel.Text = "Access the bgw...";
                    }
                    ));

        } // dr_begin_dd_check
```

I'm now getting the error in the formMain:

*Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.*

I'm not sure where the error lies in my above code or actually in the formMain section, or should i open a new question? :)

cheers guys

Graham

Comment: Don't create a second main form. Pass the existing form to the constructor of anotherform as described in my answer.

Comment: Upvote the helpfull answers and mark the answer please! That is the proper way to thank ;-)